# how to count all check boxes in a form (Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have number of check boxes that gets generated dynamically. So i do not know how many check boxes gets generated each time. I need to have some JavaScript ways to count the total numbers of check boxes in a form.

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="username1" name="check[0]" id="1" /><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="userusername2" name="check[1]" id="1" /><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" value="userusername3" name="check[2]" id="1" /><br/>
```

I can not change the name of the check boxes as i need to send the values to serverside PHP script as an array.

Comment: Your ID attributes are invalid.  They need to a) be unique, and b) start with a letter.

Comment: the id attribute is designed to identify unique elements in an HTML document. You shouldn't be reusing '1' for an id attribute in each of your checkboxes.

Comment: i admit that i did mistake in putting id value, thanks for mentioning it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since all other answers are jquery based, I'll offer a pure javascript solution. Assuming the following form:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" value="username1" name="check[0]" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername2" name="check[1]" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername3" name="check[2]" /><br/>
</form>
```

You could compute the number of checkbox elements with the following logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
var inputTags = myform.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxCount = 0;
for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i<length; i++) {
     if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox') {
         checkboxCount++;
     }
}
alert(checkboxCount);
</script>
```

BTW: As others have noted, the `id` attribute in any HTML tag should be unique within the document. I've omitted your `id="1"` attributes in my sample HTML above.

### Update:

If you simply want to count all checkbox elements on the entire page without using a containing form element, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxCount = 0;
for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i<length; i++) {
     if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox') {
         checkboxCount++;
     }
}
alert(checkboxCount);
</script>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, depending on your markup the controls may not be children of the form.  Using `myform.elements` instead of `myform.getElementsByTagName('input')` would solve that problem.

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky: If you mean the checkboxes are not *direct* children of the form, that doesn't matter, since getElementsByTagName() searches the whole subtree -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName . If you mean that the checkboxes are not children of a `<form>` element at all, well that simply wouldn't be valid HTML.

Comment: Actually, it would.  See the `form` attribute on `<input>` in HTML5.

Comment: is there any possible way without having form tag?

Comment: @Bishwo: I've updated my answer to include instructions on how to count checkbox elements without using a containing form element.

Answer (score 1):

In Plain JavaScript:

```
var myForm = document.forms[nameOrIndex];
var inputs = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxes = [];
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type').toLowerCase() == 'checkbox'){
    checkboxes.push(inputs[i]);
  }
}
alert(checkboxes.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").length);
```

If you wanted a particular form you would need to select the form and use that as a base for your call to querySelectorAll instead of document or change the selector to include the form.

```
<form id="aForm">
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername2" name="check[1]" id="1" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername3" name="check[2]" id="1" /><br/>
</form>
<form id="bForm">
    <input type="checkbox" value="username1" name="check[0]" id="1" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername2" name="check[1]" id="1" /><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="userusername3" name="check[2]" id="1" /><br/>
</form>
```

Then use:

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll("#aForm > input[type=checkbox]").length); //shows 2

alert(document.querySelectorAll("#bForm > input[type=checkbox]").length); //shows 3
```

**Note: The Selectors API is only available in newer browsers starting with: Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3.5, Safari 3.1, Chrome 1, and Opera 10.**

Comment: I think its only fair to state that `querySelectorAll()` is a newer DOM API method and not available on older browsers as it only became a W3C Candidate Recommendation in late December, 2009. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/

Comment: Agreed and I should have stated that.  I do think it is important to promote the newer DOM API methods where possible.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery

```
var len = $('input:checkbox').length;

alert(len);
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/ZWJYS/)

Comment: `$(':checkbox')` or `$('input[type=checkbox]'`) more like it. There's no 'checkbox' tag in HTML.

Comment: If he's wanting to count the checkboxes in a specific form, he'd want to use $("#formID > input[type=checkbox]").length. (And length is a property, not a method.)

Comment: @Marc B  and @BraedenP thanks I forgot the ":" and adding input before is a great point

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( $("form input[type='checkbox']").length );
```

Will give you all the checkboxes in a form, using jQuery.

Comment: I think somebody is downvoting every answer that even mentions jquery

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with `php` and you seem to use some sort of numbering already for the form fields, you can also just `echo` that php counter to a javascript variable:

```
<?php
//
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var checkbox_counter = <?php echo $your_counter_in_php; ?>
</script>
<?php
//
?>
```

By the way, in html you can only have one `id` on a page and it can´t start with a number.

Answer (score -1):

if you have jQuery you could do something like

```
alert ($(':checkbox').length ());
```

If not then you'll have to `document.getElementsByTagName ('input')`, iterate over the collection you get back and increment a counter every time you encounter one with its type attribute set to checkbox.