# Writing a for loop to create divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

What I am trying to do is write a for loop to create a certain number of divs. The number of divs depends on the information i have in a database. For example there are 15 checkboxes, i need a for loop to create a div for each checkbox the user clicked. I'm not worried about the mysql side of things right now, i'm just focusing on the for loop.

So i have a main div that is 800px wide. Let's say the user clicks 8 checkboxes, i want to figure out how to write a for loop that will create 2 rows of 4 divs, each 200px wide. so 4 divs on each row. It doesn't really matter what is in the div right now i just need to know how to tackle something like this.

Any ideas that will lead me in the right direction?

Here is some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < (the number of checkboxes clicked); i++) {
        $('body').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" />');
    }
});
```

Then div will have the same css code like width 200px blah blah blah...

I guess i need to get the checkboxes clicked from the database and make a div for each checkbox.

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: Like other people said, show us what you've done atm. We do not throw codes out of random (this is not a forum), we fix what isn't working and explain why (Q&A).

Comment: this actually works if you replace `(the number of checkboxes clicked)` with `8`, but if you want it on two rows, you need a nested loop and a vertical space after each nested loop

Comment: Added some code. I don't know if this would work or not.

Comment: for `(the number of checkboxes clicked)`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779404/how-to-count-all-check-boxes-in-a-form-javascript - All you need to change is `if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox')` to `if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputTags[i].checked)`

Comment: Well this is what happens:

1. on one page the user checks a certain number of checkboxes
2. the different checkboxes get a value in the database
3. i need the for loop to create a div for all the checkboxes that were clicked by the user

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length` to get the number checked. Instead, you can use `.each()` to loop through `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS for this?

```
<input type="hidden" id="checkboxCount" value="[# of checkboxes checked]" />

<div class='container'><!-- append HTML here--></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    for( var i = 0; i < parseInt(document.getElementById('checkboxCount').value, 10); i++) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="ckbDiv" id="div'+ i +'" />');
    }

});

.container { width: 800px; }
.ckbDiv { float: left; width: 200px; }
```

Comment: And then for the number of checkboxes just write another function that reads from the database to see which boxes were checked?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. You could pass that info from the server side in a hidden field. (Will update answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
var n_checked_checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
for (var i = 0; i < n_checked_checkboxes; i++) {
    $('<div/>', {
        'id': 'div' + i,
        'class': 'some_class_name'
    }).appendTo('body');
}
```

```
.some_class_name {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

As you have `body` with width 800px `float: left` will do second row for you, when the first row is full (4 divs)

And here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DvjxL/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of this answer ( [how to count all check boxes in a form (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779404/how-to-count-all-check-boxes-in-a-form-javascript)) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxCount = 0;
for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i<length; i++) {
     if (inputTags[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputTags[i].checked) {
         checkboxCount++;
     }
}

for(i = 0; i < checkboxCount; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" />');
    //morestuff, div related
}    
</script>
```

Count all inputs who are checkboxes and are checked. With that number, you do the `for` you made.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to get 2-dimensional coords in a table is this formula:

```
var items = ['first','second','third',....,'tenth'];
var n = items.length; // here: 10
var columns = 4;
var rows = Math.ceil(n/columns); // = 3
for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
    var coords = {
        row: Math.ceil((i+1)/columns), // will return something between 1 and 4
        col: i % columns, // will return something between 0 and 3
    };
    doSomeThingWithItem(items[i],coords);
}
```